# Who mixes for Pentatonix songs?

Tags: production

Pentatonix voices sound very clear and good.
Does anyone know who mixes for them?
And also I am curious that what kind of program/DAW do they use for their production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ben Bram](http://www.thebenbram.com/) is the primary producer, arranger, and recording engineer for Pentatonix.  Besides being an a cappella performer himself, he has extensive experience working with various groups and Hollywood shows.

I have no idea what software he uses in recording.  I did some searching of [his Tweets](https://twitter.com/thebenbram), but I didn't find any mention of his recording software.

Comment: While at the time this seemed like the right answer, the citation included in ctate's answer explicitly describes Boyer as the mixer, Bram as the producer/arranger.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't think Bram did much in the way of mixing, at least not since the earliest days.  He gets an "engineering" credit on PTX Volume 2 but not a "mixing" credit, for example.

One of their long-time mixmasters is a guy named Ed Boyer, who's been in the business for a very long time.  See for example the [Sound On Sound article about his workflow](http://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/inside-track-pentatonix), with specific examples from the eponymous "Pentatonix" full-length album.  It goes into a lot of detail about both hardware and software, mic selection, aesthetic choices about pitch and intonation correction, et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

There's [a lot of suspicion](https://www.soundonsound.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=41438&hilit=pentatonix#p379826) that Pentatonix uses pitch correction - manual or otherwise - on their recordings, but there's no evidence of that. While to many their recordings sound auto-tuned, I've learned that there *are* supremely good musicians out there.

Their producer, Ben Bram, produces a lot of a capella groups, and I imagine if he does any pitch correction at all, he'd keep that a closely held secret. (It would be a bad business move to do otherwise.)

Comment: They all have wonderful natural voices --you can hear that in their early pre-fame YouTube videos.  Of course, that doesn't mean they don't have studio help now...

Comment: fwiw Ed Boyer admits to using pitch correction (Melodyne specifically) as listeners expect that as part of the 'modern pop music sound'. It's also obvious that it's being used if you simply listen to their music.

Answer (score 1):

Ed Boyer is their production engineer. He is probably the most important acappella producer in the business. All you have to do is google him and you can find out about him and the equipment he uses as well as find an interview he did about work he's done for Pentatonix. Seems like most fans arent aware of how involved mixing and final production is.